# Object matching in Entity Framework using combobox

Tags: c#, entity-framework, combobox

The problem that occurs is that I have the same "Room number" of two different hotels and both of them are showing up because of that. So what I want to achieve is by using the selected value of the hotel I want to show the rooms for it. Screenshot below for a little clearer explanation:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5Y4h.png (don't got 10 rep so can't post it as an img)

In the view I use this code:

```
cBAddBHID.DataSource = hr.getAllHotels();
string hotelId = cBAddBHID.SelectedValue.ToString();
cBAddBRID.DataSource = rr.getMatchingRooms(hotelId);
```

In my Repository / DAL I use this

```
public List<Room> getMatchingRooms(string idToMatch)
{
    List<Room> matchingRooms = new List<Room>();

    foreach (Room r in db.Room)
    {           
        if (db.Room.Any(o => o.roomId == idToMatch))
        {
            matchingRooms.Add(r);
        }
        else
        {
            return null; 
        }
    }

    return matchingRooms;
}
```

Edit:

Screenshot of model added: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQXjd.png

Comment: Why `o.roomId == idToMatch`? May be `o.hotelId == idToMatch`? Anyway. To get appropriate support you must show your entities with its relations.

Comment: Noticed that and tried it, still not working ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your model, you could return the rooms of the hotel with:

```
        public List<Room> getMatchingRooms(string idToMatch)
        {
            return db.Room.Where(x => x.hotelId == idToMatch).ToList();
        }
```

Or, keeping your longer code that fetches all rooms into memory first:

```
        public List<Room> getMatchingRooms(string idToMatch)
        {
            List<Room> matchingRooms = new List<Room>();

            foreach (Room r in db.Room)
            {           
                if (r.hotelId == idToMatch)
                {
                    matchingRooms.Add(r);
                }
            }

            return matchingRooms;
        }
```